# How to use extract on multiple columns and name output columns based on input column names

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame of blood pressure data of the following form:

```
bpdata <- data.frame(bp1 = c("120/89", "110/70", "121/78"), bp2 = c("130/69", "120/90", "125/72"), bp3 = c("115/90", "112/71", "135/80"))
```

I would like to use the following extract command, but globally, i.e. on all bp\d columns

```
extract(bp1, c("systolic_1","diastolic_1"),"(\\d+)/(\\d+)")
```

How can I capture the digit in the column selection and use it in the column output names? I can hack around this by creating a list of column names and then using one of the apply family, but it seems to me there ought to be a more elegant way to do this.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

We could use `read.csv` on multiple columns in a loop (`Map`) with `sep = "/"` and `cbind` the `list` elements at the end with `do.call`

```
do.call(cbind, Map(function(x, y) read.csv(text= x, sep="/", header = FALSE,
    col.names = paste0(c('systolic', 'diastolic'), y)),
        unname(bpdata), seq_along(bpdata)))

#    systolic1 diastolic1 systolic2 diastolic2 systolic3 diastolic3
#1       120         89       130         69       115         90
#2       110         70       120         90       112         71
#3       121         78       125         72       135         80
```

---

Or without a loop, `paste` the columns to a single string for each row and then use `read.csv/read.table`

```
read.csv(text = do.call(paste, c(bpdata, sep="/")), 
   sep="/", header = FALSE, 
   col.names = paste0(c('systolic', 'diastolic'), 
          rep(seq_along(bpdata), each = 2)))
#  systolic1 diastolic1 systolic2 diastolic2 systolic3 diastolic3
#1       120         89       130         69       115         90
#2       110         70       120         90       112         71
#3       121         78       125         72       135         80
```

---

Or using `tidyverse`, similar option is to `unite` the column into a single one with `/`, then use either `extract` or `separate` to split the column into multiple columns

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
bpdata %>% 
    unite(bpcols, everything(), sep="/") %>% 
    separate(bpcols, into = str_c(c('systolic', 'diastolic'), 
       rep(seq_along(bpdata), each = 2)), convert = TRUE)
#  systolic1 diastolic1 systolic2 diastolic2 systolic3 diastolic3
#1       120         89       130         69       115         90
#2       110         70       120         90       112         71
#3       121         78       125         72       135         80
```